# How to concatenate javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

This may be a small issue but I am not getting rid of this . I want to concatenate the argument in a javascript function . This is my string

```
html+='<a href="javascript:showchart('+data.code+');">';
```

`data.code` value is md5 string . But if i do like this it throws the error that `fe741b62ff720a180a5960c4a2c50b27` is not defined .

I know it is taking this as constant, but how can I pass this as string within this html .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to pass a string, then you need to wrap variable in quotes, e.g:

```
html+='<a href="javascript:showchart(\''+data.code+'\');">';

//<a href="javascript:showchart('fe741b62ff720a180a5960c4a2c50b27');">
```